# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a command which sends a random image, *(waifu in this case)* using the API available at this endpoint: `https://waifu.pics/api/sfw/waifu`

The command I am executing is `test1`, here is my code:

```js
if (command === 'test1') {
      const a = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      got('https://waifu.pics/api/sfw/waifu').then(response => {
      let content = response.body;
      let Image = content.url;
      a.setTitle('test')
      a.setImage(`${Image}`)
      message.channel.send(a)
  })
}
```

The problem I am facing is the following error:

```
embed.image.url: Scheme "undefined" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format to send embeded messages

```
message.channel.send({
embed: a
})
```

or

```
message.channel.send({
embed: a,
content: "my content without embed"
})
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked, OP asked for a solution in sending an embed with an image from his API endpoint, not how to send a simple embed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `setImage()` with the variable `Image` which is the raw response from the API, however the API endpoint appears to be sending a JSON response, so you need to parse this and convert it into an array first, and fetch the URL from the `url` key.

```js
if (command === 'test1') {
    got("https://waifu.pics/api/sfw/waifu").then(response => {
        let imageData = JSON.parse(response); // Parse the JSON response from the API.

        // Prepare the embed.
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Embed Title")
            .setDescription("Embed message here!")
            .setImage(imageData.url); // Set the image.

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    });
}
```